# Word 2003 is ignoring mail merge delimiters

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003, mail-merge

I have a flat file using the semi-colon as a delimiter. This is merged with a historic Word template that has been in use for years at our office. However, recently the template has started ignoring the semi-colon delimiter causing the mail merge to fail. Has anyone else experienced this kind of behaviour/know of a fix for this?

Comment: Any changes to your system or document recently? Perhaps one of the mail merge options has been disturbed. Double check the document still using the correct delimiter during mail merge.